# Pass data between Jquery mobile pages and access with php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to display list of friends who also use the app in jquery mobile view with php and facebook graph api.Here is the code.

```
     <?php
 // List of friends who also use the app
 $request_url='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_SESSION['fb_user_id'].' /friends?access_token='.$_SESSION['access_token'].'';
 $requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
 $fb_response = json_decode($requests);
 foreach($fb_response->data as $item)
 {
    $jpdk_name=$item->name;
    $jpdk_id=$item->id;
    echo '<ul data-role="listview"  data-theme="d"  >
    <li>
    <a href="#friend_view_page"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$jpdk_id.'/picture?type=normal"><h4>'.$jpdk_name.'</h4></a>
    </li>
    </ul>';
}
?>
```

Problem is I can't Pass the data in the link with get method like this

```
<a href="friend_view_page.php?fri_profile_id='.$jpdk_id.'">
```

and use in php like $_GET['fri_profile_id']

Jquery mobile only allows to access the page with href=#id
I've tried passing the value in jquery but I can't change javascript variable to php.

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First page</h1>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>        
    <div data-role="dazzle" id="data_in_id">

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="second">
<script>
$('#second').on('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
document.getElementById("dash").innerHTML =  (data.prevPage.find('div[data-role="dazzle"]').attr('id'));

 });
</script>

  <div data-role="header">

  <a data-role="button"
    data-theme="a" href="#index">Back</a>          
           <h1>Second page</h1>
    </div>        
    <div id="dash">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery, but then native JavaScript dom manip and access functions? Have you thought about using window.location.href.hash and then sending that via ajax?

Comment: Would it work on server side? I need the fri_profile_id in php string from the link user clicked.Since I'm using jquery mobile and facebook api the url is messed up.I don't think it'll work on jquery mobile.

Comment: Just grab the hash and send it with your ajax call

Comment: I've been trying the way you mentioned.Doesn't work.Can you explain me by an example code?

Comment: Show me what you've done so far

Comment: Why I need to grab the url and send with ajax while I can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].But it doesn't also read url after the # sign.

Comment: because REQUEST_URI doesn't show you the hash. With javascript you can grab the hash and send it with your ajax request.

Comment: Solved.This is basically what I want.<script>
function thefunc (){
{
  var str= document.getElementById("nanana").name;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "set.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<button type="buton" onclick="thefunc()" id="nanana" name="Bruce Wayne">Go to this user</button>
<?php
session_start(); 
//Do refresh
var_dump ($_SESSION['the_data']);
//Do PHP
?>  set.php <?php
session_start();
// get the q parameter from URL
$_SESSION['the_data'] = $_REQUEST["q"];
?>